# Translate camera position javafx

Tags: java, javafx

So I've been messing around with JavaFX and I was wondering if it was possible to translate the camera position (move the camera) instead of translating all of the shapes in the scene.  I looked around but couldn't find anything on this.

Comment: Where did you look around? How about the `Camera` documentation?

Comment: Did you create a 3d scene? `Shape`s are 2d objects, but of course you could modify the translation of a parent or even the scene root, even if you're using a 2D scene...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a camera is just a node and so you can e.g. use the setTranslate... methods to place it wherever you like.